# How to remove iframe highlight border on focus?

Tags: html, css, iframe, focus, border

Wondering if it's possible to remove the dotted border that appears on focus of an iframe embedded within a page? The iframe contains a form that is tabbed to from some input boxes on the page that contains it. The focus border looks unsightly and would like to get rid of it. Have tried setting frameborder to 0 within the iframe, adding a hidefocus attribute and setting the border and outline to 0 through CSS to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

if iframe is not on the same domain, it is not possible

Comment: Cheers for the response. I've tried referencing a local page within the iframe and the focus border still appears? Or have I misinterpreted what you said?

Comment: do you have an url, where it happens ?